# Hide device keyboard inside keyboardWillShow notification based on some condition for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, keyboard

I am working on an iPad application which uses `Motorola CS3070 bar code scanner`. I am connecting the scanner as using HID Profile and it is treated as a bluetooth keyboard by iPad. When scanner is connected to iPad using bluetooth and if we focus on any `textfield` inside application, it won't open device virtual keyboard. This is expected as device treats bar code scanner as `bluetooth keyboard`.

While doing scanning if the scanner is disconnected, device virtual keyboard will be displayed. When this happens we want to show an alert instead of having keyboard displayed on the screen. We are using `keyboardWillShow` notification to differentiate whether device virtual keyboard is displayed or not. Inside `keyboardWillShow` we tried hiding the keyboard. This works when we disconnect the scanner and then select a text field. But this is not working when the focus was already in a `textfield` and device connects to bluetooth keyboard and if we disconnect the bluetooth. We see keyboard device virtual keyboard getting displayed in that case. I checked the code inside the `keyboardWillShow` and it is getting executed both the times. Also when it is not working, the keyboard which gets displayed on screen is not responding when we click on any keys.

Please let me know if we can hide keyboard when it switches between bluetooth keyboard to device virtual keyboard.

Please see below code in keyboardWillShow,

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *) theNotification
{
    Global *obj=[Global getInstance];
    if (obj.selectedStartScan == true) {
        UITextField *theTextField = [theNotification object];
        //[theTextField resignFirstResponder];

        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                             message:@"Scanner is not Connected"
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [self.window.rootViewController.view endEditing:YES];
         NSLog(@"inside if obj.selectedStartScan  :.........");
         [errorAlert show];

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you get notification , just call the
 `[UItextFiled ressignFirstResponder]`

This will hide the keaboard

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. I have that code commented in the code I pasted above.

Comment: Please check if `theTextField` has a valied reference to a testfiled and it has memory address, i guess the `theTextField` does not have valid reference